# How to know if our app is launched by Intent of other App

Tags: android, android-intent

I am launching my app from other app successfully, but I am unable to find the instance weather my app is launched from other app or simply by Android app launcher.

I am using this code

```
    Intent intent = getIntent(); 
    if (intent!=null && intent.getType()!=null)  //check if any application has executed your app
    {
         if(intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) 
           isinint=true; 
    }
```

The control doesn't go inside the outer `if` at all. I tried debugging intent variable, `intent.getType()` is `null` thats why the control is not entering inside.

Help !!

Comment: Both apps r developed by u ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have MainActivity defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` as follow:

```
<activity   android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

You can just check `Intent` category. If one of categories equal to `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` the app has been stared from the launcher otherwise, it hasn't been.

```
if (intent != null && intent.hasCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")) {
   //started from lanucher
}
```

Comment: Getting error in ur second line for(String category : intent.getCategories()){

Comment: @VivekWarde check that getCategories is not null.

Comment: 03-18 20:21:26.905: E/AndroidRuntime(18696): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.Set.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: so it's not Intent from launcher.

Comment: @VivekWarde I have edited my answer. It's better to check by `hasCategory()`.

Comment: `Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` is probably preferred over hard-coding the launcher String

Answer (score 1):

### Use only intent.getType()

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
            if (intent.getType() != null) {
                if (intent.getType().contains("image/")) {
                  // Started from other apps
            }
```